# rake directory command silently fails?

Tags: rake

I'm a newbie to rake so there's probably a simple explanation. I wanted to create some directories and copy in some files for a simple install script e.g.

```
task :default => ['mktd1', 'mktd2' ] do
end

task :mktd1 do
  mkdir "testdata"
  cp "x.tmp", "testdata/x.tmp"
end

task :mktd2 do
  directory "testdata1"
  cp "x.tmp", "testdata1/x.tmp"
end
```

mkdir works as long as the testdata directory doesnt already exist, but "directory" silently fails (i.e. does nothing) leading to a rake abort because the directory isn't there for the cp command.

Have I misunderstood what directory directive is supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer was I had misunderstood how rake is supposed to work. To achieve what I wanted I needed to declare a task that had a dependency on the testdata1 directory. e.g.

```
task :default => [ 'testdata1/x.tmp' ] do
end

directory "testdata1"

file "testdata1/x.tmp" => ["testdata1"] do
  cp "x.tmp", "testdata1/x.tmp"
end
```

This of course creates a file_creation task x.tmp which depends on the testdata1 directory, and a default task that depends on the x.tmp file creation task. I feel dumb.